# Replace Special characters of column names in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, replace, apache-spark-sql

I have my input `spark-dataframe` named `df` as,

```
+---------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|Main_CustomerID|126+ Concentrate|2.5 Ethylhexyl_Acrylate|
+---------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|         725153|             3.0|                    2.0|
|         873008|             4.0|                    1.0|
|         625109|             1.0|                    0.0|
+---------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

I need to remove the special characters from the column names of `df` like following,

- Remove `+`
- Replace space as `underscore`
- Replace `dot` as `underscore`

So my `df` should be like

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|Main_CustomerID|126_Concentrate|2_5_Ethylhexyl_Acrylate|
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|         725153|            3.0|                    2.0|
|         873008|            4.0|                    1.0|
|         625109|            1.0|                    0.0|
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

Using Scala, I have achieved this by,

```
var tableWithColumnsRenamed = df

for (field <- tableWithColumnsRenamed.columns) {
      tableWithColumnsRenamed = tableWithColumnsRenamed
        .withColumnRenamed(field, field.replaceAll("\\.", "_"))
    }
for (field <- tableWithColumnsRenamed.columns) {
      tableWithColumnsRenamed = tableWithColumnsRenamed
        .withColumnRenamed(field, field.replaceAll("\\+", ""))
    }
for (field <- tableWithColumnsRenamed.columns) {
      tableWithColumnsRenamed = tableWithColumnsRenamed
        .withColumnRenamed(field, field.replaceAll(" ", "_"))
    }

df = tableWithColumnsRenamed
```

When I used,

```
for (field <- tableWithColumnsRenamed.columns) {
      tableWithColumnsRenamed = tableWithColumnsRenamed
        .withColumnRenamed(field, field.replaceAll("\\.", "_"))
    .withColumnRenamed(field, field.replaceAll("\\+", ""))
    .withColumnRenamed(field, field.replaceAll(" ", "_"))
    }
```

I got the first column name as `126 Concentrate` instead of getting `126_Concentrate`

But I don't prefer 3 for loops for this replacement. Can I get the solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
df
  .columns
  .foldLeft(df){(newdf, colname) =>
    newdf.withColumnRenamed(colname, colname.replace(" ", "_").replace(".", "_"))
  }
  .show
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfect. According to my use case, I have changed the solution as,   `df.columns.foldLeft(df){(newdf, colname) => newdf.withColumnRenamed(colname,colname.replace(" ", "_").replace(".", "_").replace("+",""))}`

Answer (score 8):

You can use `withColumnRenamed` `regex replaceAllIn` and `foldLeft` as below

```
val columns = df.columns

val regex = """[+._, ]+"""
val replacingColumns = columns.map(regex.r.replaceAllIn(_, "_"))

val resultDF = replacingColumns.zip(columns).foldLeft(df){(tempdf, name) => tempdf.withColumnRenamed(name._2, name._1)}

resultDF.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|Main_CustomerID|126_Concentrate|2_5_Ethylhexyl_Acrylate|
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|725153         |3.0            |2.0                    |
|873008         |4.0            |1.0                    |
|625109         |1.0            |0.0                    |
+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

In java you can iterate over column names using `df.columns()` and replace each header string with `string replaceAll(regexPattern, IntendedCharreplacement)`

Then use `withColumnRenamed(headerName, correctedHeaderName)` to rename `df` header.

eg -

```
for (String headerName : dataset.columns()) {
    String correctedHeaderName = headerName.replaceAll(" ","_").replaceAll("+","_");
    dataset = dataset.withColumnRenamed(headerName, correctedHeaderName);
}
dataset.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking Ramesh's answer, here is a reusable function using the currying syntax with the .transform() method & makes the columns lower case:

```
// Format all column names with regex with lower_case names
def formatAllColumns(regex_string:String)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val replacingColumns = df.columns.map(regex_string.r.replaceAllIn(_, "_"))
  val resultDF:DataFrame = replacingColumns.zip(df.columns).foldLeft(df){
    (tempdf, name) => tempdf.withColumnRenamed(name._2, name._1.toLowerCase())
  }
  resultDF
}
val resultDF = df.transform(formatAllColumns(regex_string="""[+._(), ]+"""))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can remove all the characters just by mapping column_name with new name after replacing special characters using replaceAll for the respective character and this single line of code is tried and tested with spark scala.

```
df.select(
          df.columns
            .map(colName => col(s"`${colName}`").as(colName.replaceAll("\\.", "_").replaceAll(" ", "_"))): _*
        ).show(false)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does. Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.