# How to select list of specific columns (which contain special characters) from pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to select specific columns from spark dataframe.

Specific columne list is:

```python
required_cols = ['123ABC.PM','456DEF.PM']
```

Spark_df is in given format:

```python
'123ABC.PM', '54SWC.PM', '456DEF.PM', '154AS.LB'
23.5         34.5         400.7        100.3
25.4         37.6         401          100
and so on
```

I have already tried:

```python
spark_df_new = spark_df.select(required_cols)
```

But I am getting error:

```python
"cannot resolve '`123ABC.PM`' given input columns: [123ABC.PM,54SWC.PM, 456DEF.PM,154AS.LB]
``
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column name with dot spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367019/column-name-with-dot-spark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back tick ` char

```
required_cols = [`123ABC.PM`,`456DEF.PM`]
```

Comment: Back Quote works as well in Spark SQL `SELECT`  statement if your column as a special meaning such as function name

Answer (score 0):

Probably as workaround you can try below approach.

Replace the old column names with special characters to new columns and then do a select.

```
val columns = df.columns

val regex = """[+._,' ]+"""
val replacingColumns = columns.map(regex.r.replaceAllIn(_, "_"))

val resultDF = replacingColumns.zip(columns).foldLeft(df){(tempdf, name) => tempdf.withColumnRenamed(name._2, name._1)}

resultDF.show(false)
```

or

```
df
  .columns
  .foldLeft(df){(newdf, colname) =>
    newdf.withColumnRenamed(colname, colname.replace(" ", "_").replace(".", "_"))
  }
```

**Source:** [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097818/replace-special-characters-of-column-names-in-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *.
* passes the elements in your list to the selection one by one.

```
spark_df_new = spark_df.select(*required_cols)
```